# How to get cardnummer - not UID - from NFC-card

Tags: c#, nfc, smartcard

I have a card reader (ACS ACR 122u) and I need to read the NUMBER of the card.
I have tried several different code samples - and they all give the same result, in this case:

> UID: 5B2E39B2
> ATR: 3B8F8001804F0CA000000306030001000000006A

But what I'm after is the card number, in this case: "2990091867"
This number is written on the card, and also appear when the card is placed in a different card reader connected to a computer running a different application.

So, somehow, there are some common knowledge I'm missing.
Based on the data I get, is there any way to extract the card number?

Or what am i missing here?

Comment: Have you tried parsing the ATR https://smartcard-atr.apdu.fr/parse?ATR=3B8F8001804F0CA000000306030001000000006A

Comment: Mostly likely the number written on the card is stored in the user data area of the card, but as you don't specify the make and model of the Card you are trying to read it is impossible to help.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that the UID is a reversed Hex of the ID.

2990091867 to Hex => 5B2E39B2
The response I got: B2392E5B

5B 2E 39 B2 reversed => B2 39 2E 5B

Comment: Apparently you made a wrong guess on endianness; as an obfuscation step it is far too simple.